# How to get all paths from leaf to the root in a special graph

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am trying to implement an algorithm in a special data structure in graph form. my goal ist to get all paths from leaf (Target element) to the root.
This is how the graph looks like the image below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to remember all of the path that we had in order to traverse in all of the different ways on the graph, therefore only a states list isn't enough, we need a paths list. For every path we will make it longer by one if it has one parent and if it has two or more we will duplicate this list and add the parent to each one.

Well I am not great at Java and I can not run this code so I can't guarantee this will run but the algorithm is ok.

```java
public static List<ARGState> getAllErrorStatesReversed(ReachedSet reachedSet) {
  ARGState pIsStart =
      AbstractStates.extractStateByType(reachedSet.getFirstState(), ARGState.class);
  ARGState pEnd = targetStates.get(0);

  List<List<ARGState>> results = new ArrayList<>();
  List<List<ARGState>> paths = new ArrayList<>();

  paths.add(new ArrayList<ARGState>(pEnd));

  // This is assuming from each node there is a way to go to the start
  // Go on until all the paths got the the start
  while (!paths.empty()) {
    // Expand the last path on your list
    List<ARGState> curPath = paths.remove(paths.size() - 1);
    // If there is no more to expand - add this path and continue
    if (curPath.get(curPath.size() - 1) == pIsStart) {
      results.append(curPath);
      continue;
    }

    // Expand the path
    Iterator<ARGState> parents = curPath.get(curPath.size() - 1).getParents().iterator();
    // Add all parents
    while (parentElement.hasNext()) {
      ARGState parentElement = parents.next();
      List<ARGState> tmp = new ArrayList<ARGState>(List.copyOf(curPath));
      tmp.add(parentElement);
      paths.add(tmp);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Hope you understand, more than welcome to ask.
Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. All that should be happened inside my implementation right?

Comment: I am getting the output results `[id:0,Parents[]],[id:0,Parents[]],[id:0,Parents[]]` so a list of only  first element. :(

Comment: Well I have no way to run this so I cannot help you debug. Hope you understand the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks you mean about this  `paths.add(new ArrayList<ARGState>(pEnd));` that you add `pEnd` as first element of `new ArrayList` right?

Comment: I dont know why am i getting : `[id:0,Parents[]],[id:0,Parents[]],[id:0,Parents[]]` :( do you have any idea please?

Comment: i debuged it and its only 3 times true. Can i switch to `discussion chat` please? i really need your help

Comment: Yes, it should be 3 times true, since there are 3 paths. How can we move to discussion chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210572/discussion-between-catalina-and-yonlif).

Comment: I have a question please regarding the code above. What is i have large data (paths) to store? what is the best data structure to store more than 100 paths?

Comment: Hello :) I think it can deal with 100 paths just fine. Some improvements can definitely be made, like: We do not need to copy the entire `curPath` if there is only one parent. The data structure itself (stuck) is perfect for our goal. Maybe instead of `ArrayList` consider `LinkedList` and use its builtin functions to access the last element in `O(1)`, you will need to look into that. @Catalina

Comment: Thank you could you please help me with this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622143/how-to-reduce-the-complexity-of-nested-loops

Comment: i think the big o notation for this algorithm could be `O(n^2)` right? since there is nested loop

Comment: You should think about the time complexity with terms of `E` and `V` since the algorithm is `BFS` which is a graph algorithm. Usually the time complexity of BFS is `O(E + V)` but now we need to save all the different paths `O(E*V)` in the complexity.